# Paypal Pre Approved Payment Method for yearly recurrence

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, recurring-billing

My web application has the yearly recurrence payment for which i used the express checkout createRecurringPaymentProfile but that method doesn't work for german buyers. There's also an adaptive method (Pre-Approved Payment Method) which provides recurring payment within specified time. "The *endingDate* should not be more than one year from *startingDate*" is specified in the document for preapproved method by paypal. In this case if i want to implement yearly recurrence through preapproved payment method, how can i achieve that? 
Is it possible to set infinite yearly recurring cycles by not specifying *endingDate*?